# How to implement an auto refresh on a datagridview bound to a MySQL database in Visual Basic (.NET)

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net, datagridview

I have a visual basic program with a datagridview that is bound to a mysql database upon loading... I also have fields where you can update selected rows, add, delete, etc.  and I'd like to have an auto-refresh upon updating... However, I cannot figure out how to do this as the table just adds the new rows underneath the old rows.  Is there a way to have a complete table refresh for the mysql bound datagridview without having to re-launch the program?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The grid is not bound to MySQL.  It's bound to a `DataTable`.  If you want a complete refresh of the data then simply clear that table and then repopulate it.

```
myDataTable.Rows.Clear()
```

Comment: If you've cleared the `DataTable` and that's bound to the grid then there are no current rows.  I think you need to show us what you're actually doing rather than describing what you think you're doing.

Comment: The datagridview is populated from a mysql query from the database, and when I tried that code, it errors out saying "Cannot clear this list."

Comment: Are you sure that you cleared the `DataTable` and not the `DataGridView`?  Someone else took it upon themselves to edit my answer and provide code that was incorrect.  I deleted that code and replaced it with code that actually does as I described.  You cannot remove rows from a bound grid; you must work with the underlying data source, i.e. the `DataTable`.  There is no reason that you can't clear the `DataTable`, which is exactly what I said to do in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

As jmcilhinney suggested, datagridviews are bound to DataTables (or sometimes lists in my own case), so what he said sounds like it *should* work. Since, apparently, it didn't do as you wanted, here's my suggestion:

You said you have "fields" where you can update, add, delete, etc. a selected row, correct? It also sounds like you're doing *something* with new rows. As you've suggested that it's a databound gridview, I doubt that you're actually adding them in the typical way but instead have some sort of programmatic alternative.

So, try implementing your solution as less of a "rewrite" and more of a SQL update. When the user enters the data for the row that they wish to update or the new row they'd wish to create, search the rows for a given primary key.

In the case of a datatable, the code would look something like this:

```
string s = "primaryKeyValue";
DataRow foundRow = dataSet1.Tables["AnyTable"].Rows.Find(s);
foundRow.Item["DesiredColumn"] = newValue;
```

source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y06xa2h1.aspx

In the case of a list bound as a DataSource, I believe you'd have to do something like this:

```
List<Thing> things = new List<Thing>(); // in case this wasn't obvious
Thing tempThing;
tempThing = things.Find(x => x.PartName.Contains("seat")));
tempThing.Value = newValue;
```

After you've modified the underlying datasource, then, theoretically, you should be able to simply call DataGridView.Refresh(), but you may have to do something trickier like set the datasource to null and then rebind it in order to force EndEdit.

I know this is late, but I hope it still helps someone.